bit-accurate modelling of algorithm in python
I plan to implement covariance matrix inversion on an FPGA. The data will come from an ADC in 13.2-bit two's complement format (4 channels). The number of samples used for the covariance matrix is represented by "N_samples." Given this, there will be a substantial amount of multiplication required to compute the covariance matrix and its inverse. I want to determine the maximum possible size of any intermediate values to design the architecture accordingly. For matrix inversion, i am going with QRD, all the relevant algorithm are given below in python.
I want the below code to replicate how the FPGA does fixed-point arithmetic, so i can compare the software and hardware implmentation.
Matrix Multiplication
def mat_mult(mat_0, mat_1, scale_factor):
    n_row = mat_0.shape[0]
    n_col = mat_1.shape[1]
    k_dim = mat_0.shape[1] 

    mat = np.zeros((n_row, n_col), dtype=np.complex64)

    for i in range(n_row):
        for j in range(n_col):
            for k in range(k_dim):
                mat[i, j] += mat_0[i, k]*mat_1[k, j]
            mat[i, j] /= scale_factor

    return mat

QRD
def QRD(R):
    col_n = R.shape[1]   
    Q = np.eye(col_n)
    S = R

    for col in range(col_n):
        for i in range(col_n-col-1):
        
            # rotation matrix 
            G = np.eye(col_n, dtype=np.complex64)
        
            # column of interest
            column = R[:, col]

            pivot = col # pivot 
            zero = col+i+1 # zero 

            c = column[col]
            s = column[zero]
            r = np.sqrt(c**2+s**2)

            # update the rotation matrix
            G[pivot][pivot] = c/r
            G[pivot][zero] = s/r
            G[zero][pivot] = -G[pivot][zero]
            G[zero][zero] = G[pivot][pivot]

            # apply the transformation
            R = mat_mult(G, R)
            Q = mat_mult(Q, G.conj().T)

    return Q, R

Upper Triangular Matrix Inverse
def UTri_Mat_Inv(matrix):
    R_inv = np.zeros((4, 4), dtype=np.complex64)

    m44 = 1/matrix[3, 3] # 1/j
    m33 = 1/matrix[2, 2] # 1/h
    m22 = 1/matrix[1, 1] # 1/e
    m11 = 1/matrix[0, 0] # 1/a

    m34 = -matrix[2, 3]*m44*m33 # -i/(jh)
    m23 = -matrix[1, 2]*m33*m22 # -f/(eh)
    m12 = -matrix[0, 1]*m22*m11 # -b/(ae)

    m24 = m22*(-matrix[1, 3]*m44 - matrix[1, 2]*m34) # 1/e(-g/j - -fi/jh)
    m13 = m11*(-matrix[0, 2]*m33 - matrix[0, 1]*m23) # 1/a(-d/h - -cf/(eh))

    m14 = m11*(-matrix[0, 1]*m24 - matrix[0, 2]*m34 - matrix[0, 3]*m44) #1/a(-b/e(-g/j - -fi/jh) - -ci/(jh) - d/j)

    R_inv[0, 0] = m11
    R_inv[1, 1] = m22
    R_inv[2, 2] = m33
    R_inv[3, 3] = m44

    R_inv[0, 1] = m12
    R_inv[1, 2] = m23
    R_inv[2, 3] = m34

    R_inv[0, 2] = m13
    R_inv[1, 3] = m24

    R_inv[0, 3] = m14

    return R_inv

To calculate the inverse covariance matrix.
    c = mat_mult(array_data, array_data.conj().T, N_samples) # zero mean
    Q, R =  QRD(c)
    R_inv = mat_mult(UTri_Mat_Inv(R), Q.conj().T)

Are there any considerations i have to be aware of when converting float to fixed-point?
Any fixed-point lib recommendation?
How can i replicate square root function in python?

I have reviewed several packages for doing fixed point implementations in Python and from that have settled on the fpbinary package as my package of choice for doing fixed point bit/cycle accurate modelling for FPGA verification. This library was written by an FPGA developer for FPGA developers written with digital hardware in mind (following many of the VHDL fixed point library conventions, and elegantly simple).
I have presented a primer on using this library still available online through the Embedded Online Conference, and actively teach a Python course "Python Applications for Digital Design and Signal Processing" where this library is used along with other considerations on using Python for digital design verification and modeling.

It seems that the library doesn't support square root operations. As a workaround, what i did was, convert the fixed-point value to a float, compute the square root using numpy, and then convert the result back to fixed-point format. Something like this should be fine right?

yes although I stress the importance of using "bit and cycle accurate" models for purpose of verification--the result should match exactly bit for bit after each cycle. So with that you want to check that there isn't small differences due to rounding error assuming you want to use the result as I do for machine verification at the bit level. Otherwise you want to replicate the specific algorithm used. You could see Marcus' answer here for further insights on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33033940/6415629

out of curiosity, how does one implement cycle accurate model of algorithm?. It sounds complex and time consuming.

Well, I don't have a one sentence answer to that but it's what I teach in my course. It's time saving actually.

is it in DSP for SDR?

No, the course I link in this answer "Python Applications for Digital Design and Signal Processing"-- it just started through the Boston IEEE: you can sign up or get more info here: https://ieeeboston.org/courses/
